# HTML 5 Canvas + JQuery + Rails 5.2 - Not Drawing to Canvas?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, canvas

I'm able the have the canvas display a basic .html output like "**Hello world!**", but it's not drawing any shapes.

Many of the tutorials and videos I've seen write the scripts in plain Javascript. Is there a chance the problem has to do with my use of JQuery instead? Also, to keep things simple and match how many of the demos are shown, I've inlined the styling...

**canvas_test.html.erb**

```
<h1>HTML5 Canvas Playground</h1>
<section id="canvas" style='border: 1px solid, width: 800px; height: 600px;'>
  <canvas>
    Your browser does not support Canvas. Please upgrade your browser to proceed...
  </canvas>
</section>
```

When it comes to the Javascript/JQuery...

- This works insofar as it outputs text within the #canvas element

**canvas_test.coffee.js**

```
$(document).on('turbolink:load', function() {    
var canvas = $("#canvas");    
canvas.html("<b>Hello world!</b>");  });
```

- This does NOT work and even goes so far as to no longer display the original "Hello world!"...

**canvas_test.coffee.js**

```
 $(document).on('turbolink:load', function() {
   var canvas = $("#canvas");
   var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

   canvas.html("<b>Hello world!</b>");
   context.fillStyle = 'blue';
   context.fillRect(250, 50, 100, 100);
 });
```

Any idea what I'm overlooking here? Thank you for helping me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues here:

1. Your `canvas` jQuery variable is *not* selecting the actual HTML `canvas` element, but rather the `section` that wraps the HTML `canvas` element.
2. Even if you were selecting the actual `canvas` element, you would be working with the jQuery representation of that element and not that element itself. This will cause an error like `canvas.getContext is not a function`. To work with the DOM element that the jQuery variable represents, you can use `canvas[0]`, and then can call `getContext` like this: `canvas[0].getContext('2d')`.
3. You're not seeing the "Hello world" text because the function is erroring out as a result of #1 and/or #2. Even when you do solve those issues, you still won't see that text because putting that text inside the `canvas` element will not render it on the canvas. If you want to see that text on your `canvas`, you'll need to do something like: `context.fillText("Hello World",10,50)`

Putting it all together, your HTML should look like this:

```
<h1>HTML5 Canvas Playground</h1>
<section style='border: 1px solid, width: 800px; height: 600px;'>
  <canvas id="canvas" >
    Your browser does not support Canvas. Please upgrade your browser to proceed...
  </canvas>
</section>
```

And your JavaScript should look like this:

```
var canvas = $("#canvas");
var context = canvas[0].getContext('2d');
context.fillStyle = 'blue';
context.fillRect(250, 50, 100, 100);
context.font = "12px Arial";
context.fillText("Hello World",10,50);
```

I created a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zjjdXK) with the above code so you can see it in action.

Comment: Thank you R. F. Nelson, you explained it well! I appreciate your CodePen too!